# mvn --version throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, chef-infra

Through chef I have installed the maven in a amazonlinux2 instance. When I run the "mvn --version" command as a ec2-user I am getting proper output like below one but when I run the same command as ROOT I am getting ClassNotfoundException error. Not sure what is missing. I checked the directory permissions and everything looks good. Able to see the java version on both the linux user account.

**As EC2-User:**

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 11.0.14.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java home: /usr/java/jdk-11.0.14.1+1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.290-217.505.amzn2.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**As ROOT user:**

```
# mvn --version
Error: Could not find or load main class \
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \
```

Comment: Why not just unzip an official distribution?

Comment: However you do please use a more recent version of Maven, because 3.0.3 is 11 years old...If you have used chef use it to install via download etc.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise for the inputs. I used very latest version and the issue was persist. I found the issue and its been resolved now. Now both old and new Maven are working fine

Comment: But use the most recent version.. because the old ones have a lot of bugs..

Answer (score 1):

**Issue has been resolved** after modifying the .mavenrc file which is present in the /root/ home dir. There was a plenty of space between two arguments which was separated by a new line character. I removed everything and kept a single space between two arguments in the MAVEN_OPTS variable defined in the .mavenrc file.